# how to retain form values in jquery chosen plugin on form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

can anyone tell me how I can retain form values in chosen jquery plugin on form submit.
I am using form submit to fetch the data and display on the same page below form. I have this form in many places So cannot change it to Async Ajax. So please suggest me if chosen has the feature or if not how can i do that in chosen.

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8100644/9192488/2b867c36-4029-11e5-89cb-673f4c7d2ba5.png

selected values should be retained and should be disable for user to select again

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form:select class="form-control chosen-select inputText" path="facilitiesList" name="facilitiesList" id="facilitiesList" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="${facilityMultiSelect}" multiple="true" style='overflow:hidden'></form:select>
```

```
var config = {
    '.chosen-select' : {}
};
$
                .ajax( {
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "/logistics/autoCompl/fetchFacilities.do",
                    dataType : "json",
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    success : function(response) {
                        availableFacilities = response;
                        $.each(response, function(i, value){
                              $('#facilitiesList').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
                           });

                        for (var selector in config) {
                              $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
                            }
                        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    },
                    error : function(e) {

                        alert("Technical Exception occured while searching for Invoices.");

                        // alert('Error: ' + e.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sushilsingh94/tdzh68hv/7/

Comment: you need to show how you init your Chosen plugin.

Comment: @Neverever updated initialization for chosen plugin for the field

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @atoms provided jsfiddle link for the sample

Comment: what serverside languge are you using? Could just echo the post values

Comment: if your using post, change the action to `action=""` and then if using php you could use, `if(isset($_POST['option'])){
  if($_POST['option'] == 'American Black Bear'){
    echo "search-choice";
  }
}`
to echo a class to be picked up by jquery?